# SD Card readable only on my Android

Tags: filesystems, android, sd-card, filesystem-corruption

Do you have any hints on understanding what's the reason for this?

I have an SanDisk SD Card that exhibits a strange behavior:

1. Has data on it and the content is read by my HTC One M9.
2. From time to time from it I get errors stating that the sd card was removed. **I believe that the card has some problems. I will get rid of it after I understand what's happening.**
3. When I try to `adb pull` data I get same errors after a while.
4. In Windows 10 the card is not detected in Disk Management. I have a letter i:\ comming from the SD Card Reader but I cannot format it as it doesn't detect a disk.
5. In OSX the card is not detected.
6. The card is not detected on other mobile devices: samsung.
7. When the card is plugged in my HTC I connected to the htc via adb shell I get that **file system type is texfat**. See adb shell details at the end.
8. I have a identical card that i can see both in windows and phone.
9. After I tried to format it in HTC I've got a message:

   > **Unsupported SanDisk SD card** This device doesn't support this SanDisk SD card. Tap to set up in a supported format.`

   After I continue with Set up you SanDisk SD card - Use as removable storage. Format as portable storage.

   Then I get the message `command '196 volume partition disk:179,32 public' failed with null`

### adb shell

```
htc_himauhl:/storage/3662-3433 $ df -H
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
tmpfs                                    1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /storage
/data/media                               25G   10G   15G  39% /storage/emulated
/mnt/media_rw/3662-3433                   64G   19G   45G  30% /storage/3662-3433
htc_himauhl:/storage/3662-3433 $
```

```
mount -v
...
/dev/block/vold/public:179,33 on /mnt/media_rw/3662-3433 type texfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,umask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=utf8,min_prealloc_size=64k,max_prealloc_size=60874k,readahead=4M,fail_safe,discard,hidden=show,errors=continue)
/dev/block/vold/public:179,33 on /mnt/secure/asec type texfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,umask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=utf8,min_prealloc_size=64k,max_prealloc_size=60874k,readahead=4M,fail_safe,discard,hidden=show,errors=continue)
/mnt/media_rw/3662-3433 on /mnt/runtime/default/3662-3433 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,mask=6,gid=1015)
/mnt/media_rw/3662-3433 on /storage/3662-3433 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,mask=6,gid=1015)
/mnt/media_rw/3662-3433 on /mnt/runtime/read/3662-3433 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,mask=18,gid=9997)
/mnt/media_rw/3662-3433 on /mnt/runtime/write/3662-3433 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,mask=18,gid=9997)
```

Comment: The card is screwed, it maybe that the 'working' device (it isn't actually working, just lucky to get any information) is using higher voltages to pull data or something like this.

Comment: I agree with previous commenter, the card is toast... For the cost of sd cards just trash this one and get a new one. I would also avoid Sandisk in mobile devices and stick with Samsung EVO or Pro series microSD cards (this is not personal preference, this a recommendation from helping several dozen, perhaps hundreds, of people with SD card issues on mobile devices, Samsung cards seem to be the most reliable in mobile applications but hardly impervious to failure).

Comment: Can you boot a live install of linux, install exfat-utils, mount the device, and copy files off it? You can also use dd to make a raw backup of the device and try to get the files off it that way. Linux is usually more successful at times like this.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Too bad I cannot upvote some. I'll try a boot in linux. Thanks for the advice on brands.